# Remove Empty Nodes from HTML String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am working on an HTML template where I have to remove some text from an HTML string through javascript. The problem is sometimes empty tags remains in the HTML string as there inside content is removed.

```
<ul>
<li><strong style="font-size: 10pt;"></strong><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> </span></li>
</ul>
<p><span>. Nunc sodales ullamcorper purus, in pharetra quam dictum at. Nullam iaculis, ex ut gravida commodo, nisi odio volutpat sapien, ut mattis eros est vel turpis. Nunc at eros quis nisl efficitur sagittis. Aliquam sed risus nec ex suscipit placerat. </span></p>
<ul>
<li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In congue velit sodales ipsum tincidunt, et ullamcorper massa consectetur.</li>
<li>Nulla id ex eu elit congue consequat at ut odio. Nullam risus lorem, auctor ac nibh sed, suscipit condimentum augue.</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in first ul tag has multiple empty tags inside it which I want to remove otherwise it creates a blank bullet list item.

```
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHTML = str;
str = CleanChildren(tempDiv);

function CleanChildren(elem)
                {
                    var children = elem.childNodes;
                    var len = elem.childNodes.length;
                    document.getElementById("remarksContinue").innerHTML = "No of Child Node :: " + len;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    {
                        var child = children[i];

                        if(child.hasChildNodes())
                            CleanChildren(child);
                        else
                            elem.removeChildNode(child);

                    }

                    return elem.innerHTML;
                }
```

Above is the function which I am trying to use but no luck.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for recursion here - simply check the `textContent` of the outer element, and if its `trim`med value is the empty string, remove the element:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(container.children.length);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  container.children,
  node => {
    if (node.textContent.trim() === '') node.remove();
  }
);

console.log(container.children.length);
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><strong style="font-size: 10pt;"></strong><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> </span></li>
  </ul>
  <p><span>. Nunc sodales ullamcorper purus, in pharetra quam dictum at. Nullam iaculis, ex ut gravida commodo, nisi odio volutpat sapien, ut mattis eros est vel turpis. Nunc at eros quis nisl efficitur sagittis. Aliquam sed risus nec ex suscipit placerat. </span></p>
  <ul>
    <li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In congue velit sodales ipsum tincidunt, et ullamcorper massa consectetur.</li>
    <li>Nulla id ex eu elit congue consequat at ut odio. Nullam risus lorem, auctor ac nibh sed, suscipit condimentum augue.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another simplest way you can try it. Please see below example,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.myclass ul li").each(function(i) {
    if (this.innerText.trim() === "") {
      this.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
  <ul>
    <li><strong style="font-size: 10pt;"></strong><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> </span></li>
  </ul>
  <p><span>. Nunc sodales ullamcorper purus, in pharetra quam dictum at. Nullam iaculis, ex ut gravida commodo, nisi odio volutpat sapien, ut mattis eros est vel turpis. Nunc at eros quis nisl efficitur sagittis. Aliquam sed risus nec ex suscipit placerat. </span></p>
  <ul>
    <li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In congue velit sodales ipsum tincidunt, et ullamcorper massa consectetur.</li>
    <li>Nulla id ex eu elit congue consequat at ut odio. Nullam risus lorem, auctor ac nibh sed, suscipit condimentum augue.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number=1;
var clearnode=document.getElementById("clearnode");
function removeitem()
{
clearnode.removeChild(clearnode.children[0]);
}
function removeitemall()
{
var len=clearnode.children.length;

for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
{
clearnode.removeChild(clearnode.children[0]);

}

}
function additem(text)
{
var newel=document.createElement("li");
newel.innerText=text+" "+number;
clearnode.append(newel);
number++;
}
```

```html
<ul id="clearnode">
<li><strong style="font-size: 10pt;"></strong><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> </span></li>
</ul>
<p><span>. Nunc sodales ullamcorper purus, in pharetra quam dictum at. Nullam iaculis, ex ut gravida commodo, nisi odio volutpat sapien, ut mattis eros est vel turpis. Nunc at eros quis nisl efficitur sagittis. Aliquam sed risus nec ex suscipit placerat. </span></p>
<ul>
<li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In congue velit sodales ipsum tincidunt, et ullamcorper massa consectetur.</li>
<li>Nulla id ex eu elit congue consequat at ut odio. Nullam risus lorem, auctor ac nibh sed, suscipit condimentum augue.</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="additem('new ltem')">add item</button>
<button onclick="removeitem()">add item</button>
<button onclick="removeitemall()">add item</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you get all html tags as string then you can replace all empty tags using regex that match only empty tags `/<[^/>]+>[ \n\r\t]*<\/[^>]+>/gim` as following code

```
var str = '<ul><li><strong style="font-size: 10pt;"></strong><span style="fontsize: 10pt;"> </span></li></ul><p><span>. Nunc sodales ullamcorper purus, in pharetra quam dictum at. Nullam iaculis, ex ut gravida commodo, nisi odio volutpat sapien, ut mattis eros est vel turpis. Nunc at eros quis nisl efficitur sagittis. Aliquam sed risus nec ex suscipit placerat. </span></p><ul><li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In congue velit sodales ipsum tincidunt, et ullamcorper massa consectetur.</li><li>Nulla id ex eu elit congue consequat at ut odio. Nullam risus lorem, auctor ac nibh sed, suscipit condimentum augue</li></ul>';

    var regex = /<[^/>]+>[ \n\r\t]*<\/[^>]+>/gim;
    while(regex.test(str)){
      str = str.replace(regex, "")
    }

    alert(str)
```

output: only non empty tags

```
<p><span>. Nunc sodales ullamcorper purus, in pharetra quam dictum at. Nullam iaculis, ex ut gravida commodo, nisi odio volutpat sapien, ut mattis eros est vel turpis. Nunc at eros quis nisl efficitur sagittis. Aliquam sed risus nec ex suscipit placerat. </span></p><ul><li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In congue velit sodales ipsum tincidunt, et ullamcorper massa consectetur.</li><li>Nulla id ex eu elit congue consequat at ut odio. Nullam risus lorem, auctor ac nibh sed, suscipit condimentum augue</li></ul>
```

Comment: can we modify the above regex so that it also looks for tags having only white spaces?

Comment: @PrashantChaudhary yes it removes empty tags only so I used while loop

Comment: <LI> <STRONG style="FONT- SIZE: 10pt"> </STRONG><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt"> </SPAN> </LI></UL>

Comment: I am getting the final result as this:

Comment: <UL>
<LI> </LI></UL>
<P><SPAN> ra quam dictum at. Nullam iaculis, ex ut gravida commodo, nisi odio volutpat sapien, ut mattis eros est vel turpis.
Nunc at eros quis nisl efficitur sagittis. Aliquam sed risus nec ex suscipit placerat. </SPAN></P>
<UL>
<LI>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In congue velit sodales ipsum tincidunt, et ullamcorper massa consectetur.
<LI>Nulla id ex eu elit congue consequat at ut odio. Nullam risus lorem, auctor ac nibh sed, suscipit condimentum augue. </LI></UL>

Comment: this html not well formatted it has to be <UL><LI> <STRONG style="FONT- SIZE: 10pt"> </STRONG><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt"> </SPAN> </LI></UL>

Comment: I used the same input in your question it is working fine what is your input?